# Use of flatmap instead of foreach to generate a Hashmap

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

Having a Role class, that contains a list of View, each view has a list of subviews, and the subview has a list of KPIs.

```java
class Role {
    private final String roleName;
    private final List<View> views;
}

class View {
    private final String viewName;
    private final List<SubView> subViews;
}

class SubView {
    private final String subViewName;
    private final List<String> kpis;
}
```

I want to generate a hashmap from a list of Roles that has this pattern: viewName|subviewName as a key, and the kpis list as value.

this is achieved using foreach like :

```java
private Map<String, List<String>> getViewKpis(List<Role> roles) {
        Map<String, List<String>> viewKpis = new HashMap<>();
        roles.forEach(role -> role.getViews()
                .forEach(view -> view.getSubViews()
                        .forEach(subView -> {
                            String key = String.join("|", view.getViewName(), subView.getSubViewName());
                            if (Optional.ofNullable(viewKpis.get(key)).isPresent())
                                viewKpis.put(key, Stream.concat(viewKpis.get(key).stream(), subView.getKpis().stream()).distinct().toList());
                            else viewKpis.put(key, subView.getKpis());
                        })));
        return viewKpis;
    }
```

and I'm wondering if I can achieve the same result using the declarative approach using streams, flatMap, and so on.

Comment: It looks like it'd be a fair amount of work to do that, tbh.  The _simplest_ code to solve this problem is just going to do what you've done here,  except using normal `for` loops instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can flat map to an intermediate `Entry<View, SubView>` and then flat map again to kpis:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getViewKpis(List<Role> roles) {
    return roles.stream()
            .flatMap(role -> role.getViews().stream())
            .flatMap(view -> view.getSubViews().stream().map(sub -> Map.entry(view, sub)))
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getKey().getViewName() + "|" + e.getValue().getSubViewName(),
                    flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().getKpis().stream(), toList())));
}
```

If you're doing a lot of this type of paired streaming, you might want to consider [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).

Comment: Seems you overlooked the `distinct()` in the OP’s code. So the downstream collector would have to collect into a `LinkedHashSet` first, before converting to a `List`. Like `collectingAndThen(flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().getKpis().stream(), toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)), ArrayList::new)`

Comment: the e parameter is not recognized under the groupingBy block so e.getKey cannot be resolved. and as @Holger said I need this distinct to be applied